# Handling Multiple if/else and Special Cases

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

So I'm fairly new to coding only having relatively simple scripts here and there when I need them for work. I have a document that has an ID column formatted as:

"Number Word Number" and some values under a spec, lower tol, and upper tol column.
[image]

Where sometimes the number under ID is a integer or float and the word can be one of say 30 different possibilities. Ultimately these need to be read and then organized depending on the spec and lower/upper tol columns into something like below:

[image]

I'm using Pandas to read the data and do the manipulations I need so my question isn't so much of a how to do it, but more of a how should it best be done.

The way my code is written is basically a series of if statements that handle each of the scenarios I've come across so far, but based on other peoples code I've seen this is generally not done and as I understand considered poor practice. It's very basic if statements like:

if(The ID column has "Note" in it) then its a basic dimension
if(The ID column has Roughness) then its an Ra value
if(The ID column has Position in it) then its a true position etc

Problem is I'm not really sure what the "correct" way to do it would be in terms of making it more efficient and simpler. I have currently a series of 30+ if statements and ways to handle different situations that I've run into so far. Virtually all the code I've written is done in this overly specific and not very general coding methodology that even though it works I find personally overcomplicated but I'm not really sure what capabilities of python/pandas I'm sort of missing and not utilizing to simplify my code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to test what the variable in ID is and do some staff accordingly you can't avoid the if statements most probably.What i suggest you to do since you have written the code is to reform the database.If there is not a very specific reason you have database with a structure like this,you should change it asap.
To be specific to ID add an (auto)increment unique number and break the 3 datapoints of ID column into 3 seperate columns.